# Regular radiobutton in Repeater

Tags: asp.net

Trying to setup a regular Radiobutton in a repeater

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <input type="radio" name="OptGroup" id="rbEmail" value="<%=ID %>"/><label for="rbEmail"><%=Action %></label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

I'm trying to think through if I'm missing anything here.  I'll have a group of radiobuttons and I believe I can't just hard code the id.  That I need a unique ID for each right?

Comment: It seems like you have thought through this, but have not tried to implement it. You might want to see if it works or not before asking the question.

Comment: Exactly what problem are you having?

Comment: No, not MVC...but have.  Haven't been in MVC for a while.  I've knocked my head against issues that cannot be resolved with asp.net radiobuttonlist and radiobutton so resorting to plain old html!  After spending a day troubleshooting, I'm exhausted and just wanted to verify how to wire up.

Comment: I'm just wondering about the id.  I don't think I need to be appeding anything to it since that's only asp.net that does this

Comment: It also looks like Action is a reserved word for a generic type or something so I might have to change my DB field name for this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I'm reading this right, you're missing the datasource for the repeater, and "ID" and "Action" are part of that datasource?  In that case, you want something more like this:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" runat="server">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <input type="radio" name="OptGroup" id='<%#"rbEmail"+Eval("ID")%>' value='<%# Eval("ID") %>'/><label for="rbEmail"><%# Eval("Action") %></label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:Repeater>
```

Comment: Thanks.  And I think I can use <%#Container.DataItem.FieldName instead of Eval

Comment: Joel,  there was an extra = sign and the quotes weren't mismatched, I edited, I hope you don't mind.

Comment: but doesn't the for attribute have to also have '<%#"rbEmail"+Eval("ID")%>'

Comment: Oops: yes, those need to match.